# adding strings to a vector of vector

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I was trying to add a string to the end of a vector of vector of strings, and somehow encountered memory problem.

my code is something similar to this

```
vector<vector<string>> slist;

....

slist.push_back(vector1);
slist.push_back(vector2);

...

for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    int length = slist.size()-1;
    slist[length].push_back("String"); // also tried slist.back().push_back("S");
}
```

And this some how gives me a memory problem

```
Invalid read of size 8
==2570==    at 0x404D18: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>              >::push_back(std::string const&) (stl_vector.h:735)
==2570==    by 0x403956: main (asm.cc:400)
==2570==  Address 0xfffffffffffffff0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==2570==
==2570==
==2570== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==2570==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0
==2570==    at 0x404D18: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::push_back(std::string const&) (stl_vector.h:735)
==2570==    by 0x403956: main (asm.cc:400)
==2570==
```

Can anyone tell me why??

PS: sorry about the previous poorly asked question..

Comment: `slist.back()` is better, but we need an SSCCE. I don't believe you've shown the right code.

Comment: "a memory problem"? What kind of memory problem? What error are you getting? You've shown us code we can't use to reproduce the problem, and said that you get an error without telling us which error it *is*. The most specific answer I can give under those circumstances is "there is probably a way to make your code work"

Answer (score 1):

The code as you gave it [works fine](https://ideone.com/14E6qO):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print(vector<vector<string>> s)
{
    cout << "Lists:" << endl;
    for (const auto& v : s)
    {
        cout << "List: ";
        for (const auto& i : v)
        {
            cout << i << ", ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "Done" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<string>> slist;

    slist.push_back(vector<string>());
    slist.push_back(vector<string>());

    print(slist);

    const auto length = slist.size()-1;
    slist[length].push_back("String"); // also tried slist.back().push_back("S");

    print(slist);
}
```

Edit: Yes, you can even put it [into a loop](https://ideone.com/xgO0ty):

```
vector<vector<string>> slist;

print(slist);

for (auto i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
{
    slist.push_back(vector<string>());
    for (auto j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
    {
        slist[i].push_back("String[" + toStr(i) + "][" + toStr(j) + "]"); // also tried slist.back().push_back("S");
    }
}

print(slist);
```

The problem is probably somewhere else. What does your debugger say?

Comment: humm... thats weird...if this code is in a for loop, will it affect the result?

Comment: @user1948847, Really, post an [sscce](http://sscce.org). It's not hard and it's a lot more valuable.

Comment: @user1948847 - Putting the code in a loop works fine: https://ideone.com/xgO0ty